# android emulator - any accessible storage space?

Tags: android, file, emulation, permission-denied

I am getting

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Img_1316563834614.jpg (Permission denied)
```

after trying

```
mRAF = new RandomAccessFile(mFullPath, "rws");
```

where mFullPath was /sdcard/image6456.jpg, /mnt/sdcard/image3579.jpg, file:///sdcard/image34567.jpg, etc. Nothing works. There is already an

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

line in AndroidManifest.xml

I have checked that the path /mnt/sdcard is actually there. Also the call

```
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

gives out null. I should not wonder though...

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to try it on a device? I have found emulator testing to be shoddy at best.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it would be cumbersome to test it on a device in my setup

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do? And why are you dealing with both `/sdcard` and `/mnt/sdcard` If you want the external storage directory you can easily access to with: `getExternalStorageDirectory ()` method which will return the right absolute path of the sdcard, avoiding trouble. Have a look here for more if not yet [Environnement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The emulator does not come with external storage, unless you define some in the AVD. See the "SD Card" group box in the Add Android Virtual Device or Edit Android Virtual Device dialogs:

[image]

In this one, I defined 32MB of external storage. By default, the Size field is blank, meaning no external storage.

Comment: And as usual, we have a winner ;)