# Android - Creating txt file in sdcard

Tags: java, android

~NO NEED HELP ANYMORE, THANKS~

I have been looking for this answer on this site, but none of the code worked.

Here is my function:

```
public void onClickTemp(View view)
{

}
```

Using this function, I want to write code that creates a *.txt file in an sdcard with some text in it. I would be happy for examples how to read and change this *.txt file as well, but let's start with creating one.

I do have permission to write to external storage, and I checked the file explorer with DDMS.

Edit:
I succeed creating txt file (:

The problem was: My emulator didn't have SD card.

Solution:[android emulator - any accessible storage space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493225/android-emulator-any-accessible-storage-space)

Edit2:
Figured out about reading files (:

Solution:[How can I read a text file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-to-read-text-file-in-android)

Edit3:

Understood editing aswell( found some guide in google, i don't have link sorry)

At this moment, i don't have anymore questions, thanks for help!

Comment: It still doesn't work
Here the errors on DDMS:
01-31 09:45:53.119: W/System.err(6258): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/Notes/banana.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Althought i did write permission in manifest file..

Comment: Are you testing with a device or emulator?

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm testing with the emulator, and i tried with code that GhostDerfel gave( on link), but thats not the first code, i have tried many others aswell.

Comment: have you tried using the app dir path? (context.getFilesDir())

Comment: No.. i have no idea what is that. Can you give full example of what to write inside my onclick function?

Comment: Your emulator may not have any external storage mounted.  Aside from that, to the degree to which this is even a question, it is a duplicate as already pointed out.

Comment: In DDMS file explorer i can see the folders and files, however the SD card is empty, maybe you right that it's not mounted, than how to mount it?

Comment: OMG THAT WORKS, yes my SD card wasnt mounted!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493225/android-emulator-any-accessible-storage-space
however, Chris Stratton i have to give you reputation for your help, how to do that?
By the way, now how to read/change files?! (:

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I succeed creating txt file (:

The problem was: My emulator didn't have SD card.

Solution:[android emulator - any accessible storage space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493225/android-emulator-any-accessible-storage-space)

Edit2: Figured out about reading files (:

Solution:[How can I read a text file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-to-read-text-file-in-android)

Edit3:

Understood editing aswell( found some guide in google, i don't have link sorry)